# How do I update a navbar element from application controller?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

This is my first project, it's in Rails.   I went crazy with the modals, the whole site is modals.   I've got a bootstrap navbar, and in the navbar there's a link who's text I want to automatically change if the user gets a notification.   In my application controller I've got a :before_action

```
 @notifications = Notification.where(recipient: current_fan).unread
```

Since the whole site is modals, most views gets rendered into a modal via a js.erb, which updates the particular div in the modal with the corresponding view.   If a user receives a notification when they're inside the modal, I want the navbar link text to change so it's visible when they hide the modal.

However, I don't know how to accomplish this.  I have added this code at the top of every js.erb file, in the hopes that it would change the navbar #notification_link, so the new link text is visible when the modal is hidden, but it does not.

```
<% if @notifications.any? %>
  $("#notification_link").html('<%= link_to "NEW NOTIFICATION", notification_nmodal_index_path, "data-toggle"=>"modal", "data-target"=>"#actionModal", "id"=>"notoLink", remote: true %>')
<% end %>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this to the top of every js.erb file:

```
<% if @notifications.any? %>
  $("#navbar_notification_link").html("<%= j render 'notifications/new_notification' %>")
<% end %>
```

and in _new_notification i put

```
<%= link_to "NEW NOTIFICATION", notification_nmodal_index_path, "data-toggle"=>"modal", "data-target"=>"#actionModal", "id"=>"notoLink", remote: true %>
```

so now if user is doing something in the modal, and notification comes in, the new text on link is added for when the user hides the modal.  updating navbar element only worked if i rendered a view in it (it didn't work if i tried to update the element directly from the js.erb file).

i feel pretty good about it - i'm no developer, and i've been trying to think of a way to do it for days now, maybe even weeks.